# Linear algebra (Please Please do help me) -exercise problem on vector dimesions

Tags: linear-algebra

$2.$ Find the dimensions of

(a) the space of all vectors in $R^n$ whose components add to zero;

(c) the space of all solutions to $\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} −3 \frac{dy(t)}{dt} +2y(t) = 0$.

for (a) Im pretty sure that the dimension is $n-1$ but people seem to differ, I thought it is $n-1$ since there is a condition of components adding to zero, but I can't make up with the basis could someone help??
and for (c) its a differential equation, Ive dealt with polynomial matrixes, but this is my first time to encounter one that involves differential factor does I really am curious about the basis of (c) since the dimension will equal to the rank of the basis right??

Comment: Can you tell us what $R_n$ is? With d2y(t)dt2 you mean $\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2}$?

Comment: yes yes thats definitely it!

Answer (score 1):

a) The dimension is n-1

You could have a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3\cdots x_{n-1}, -\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} xi)$
And that vector has $n-1$ components that are independent.

b) that diff eq has a solution $y = C_1 e^{t}+ C_2 e^{2t}$

$e^{t}, e^{2t}$ form the basis of a 2 dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 0):

For first choose (0,0,...,0,1,0,...0,-1) where 1 is in the i th place i=1 to n-1. 
For the second the general solution is a.e^2x +b e^x. So the dimension is 2. Since e^2x and e^x are linearly independent functions.

Comment: thank u so much TT  does that mean the dimension for the first question is n-1??